# Como fazer um campo TextBox receber somente valores inteiros no VB6?

Tags: visual-basic-6

Tem como fazer um campo de um `textbox` só receber valores inteiros?

Comment: ASP.NET, Windows Forms, ou WCF?

Answer (score 2):

No evento `Change` do **TextBox**, verifique se o valor digitado é número, se não for então atribua o valor antigo.

```
Dim textval As String
Dim numval As String

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
  textval = TextBox1.Text
  If IsNumeric(textval) Then
    numval = textval
  Else
    TextBox1.Text = CStr(numval)
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No evento `KeyPress` de seu TextBox adicione a seguinte verificação:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
     if not IsNumeric(Chr$(KeyAscii)) then 
           KeyAscii= 0
           exit sub
     end if
End Sub
```